# How do I loop through all record and update a field from a lookup into a multi pick list?

Tags: field-update, update, multi-select

The user decided the 'Program' field should allow multiple programs. So I created a new field that uses multi pick list. So now I want to loop through and copy the field 'ABC' to the multi pick list option 'ABC'

Do I need to code this or is there a tool?

More Clearly:

There is a book object with a NAME and a GENRE (Action/Horror/Comedy). People have used this for a few months.

One day they realize they want the book object to have MANY genres. A new field is created called GENRES (it is a multi pick list of the collection (Action/Horror/Comedy)to hold these... So now a book can be a Action AND a Comedy.

The problem is. There is already 5000 records that use the old GENRE field.

How do I copy that GENRE field to the new GENRES field for all the records?

does that make sense ?

Comment: specify your question more clearly.

Comment: For one time data migration use dataloader to export the records to be updated in .csv and edit necessary info in csv and finally upload the data through dataloader

Comment: The field types are difference (lookup vs. mult pick list). But I will explore the dataloader. I have never used it.

Comment: A multi pick list is not a suitable replacement for a lookup unless the lookup was not the best choice in the first place. Should be using a junction object to associate multiple child

Comment: the lookup was not the best choice. They did not know at the time they would need multiple programs associated with an event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Open the Dataloader and select the object and export the all the data in .csv format.
- Now, go to dataloader again, select the update button, then select the same object, when it will ask for field mapping between .csv and SFDC fields,

  - remove the previous SFDC field name `GENRE` from the mapping.
  - select new field `GENRES` of SFDC and map with the .csv field `GENRE`.

Basically, replacing the column names the of the mapping.
And finally upload the data.

Refer: [Dataloader youtube video for guidance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93gElW3195A)

Comment: 'a02V0000001pLpG' is not a valid Saleforce ID for the type Book

Comment: So I may have got it wrong earlier.. The singular object is its own object and that value is a reference... it doesn't have the actual value... make sense?

Comment: Then you need to prepare the .csv properly, taking correct reference Id and then map the fields and upload the data

Comment: ok.. got it.. I need the __r to get to the object

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly and it is a picklist to multi-picklist value copy you need to do, I would use the [Developer Console's Execute Anonymous](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_execute_anonymous.htm&language=en&type=0).

The code you would need to execute would be:

```
Book__c[] books = [select Id, Genre__c from Book__c where Genres__c = null];
for (Book__c book : books) {
    book.Genres__c = book.Genre__c;
}
update books;
```

Multi-select picklist use a semi-colon as a separator but you don't need to worry about that here as you are only copying in a single value.

If there were a lot more records so that governor limits were hit, you could add say `limit 5000` to the query and execute the code multiple times.

Comment: Genre__c is a 'Custom object' with one field that is the name which is 'Program Name' (Text (80)) so that does not work.

Comment: how do I say... book.Genres__c = book.Genre__c.Name ?

Comment: Invalid foreign key relationship: Book__c.Program__c

Comment: Book__c[] books = [select Id, Program__c from Book__c where BookPickList__c = null];
for (Book__c book : books) {
    book.BookPickList__c = book.Program__c.Name;
}
update books;

Comment: does that make sense ?

Comment: Book__c[] books = [select Id, Program__c from Book__c where BookPickList__c = null];
for (Book__c book : books) {
    book.BookPickList__c = book.Program__c[0].Name;
}
update books;

Comment: I guess I want to access the first item like above somehow ?